# Preserve Color-Depth of imported Images

Tags: image-processing, processing, color-depth

When importing Images with the

```java
loadImage("...")
```

Command, iterating over the pixels in like this:

```java
img.loadPixels(); 
int w = img.width;
int h = img.height;
for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
  for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
    int loc = x + y*w;
    float r = red(img.pixels[loc]);
    float g = green(img.pixels[loc]);
    float b = blue(img.pixels[loc]);
    println(r + ", " + g + ", " + b);
  }
}
```

The R G B Values always seem to be between 0 and 255 even if the image file has a depth of 16 bit per channel, where the values should be between 0 and 65535. 
Is it possible to preserve the correct color depth?

Comment: Can't you just multiply the numbers by `65535/255`?

Comment: This would not work, because even though the numbers r g and b are stored as floats, they are basically integers, thus multiplying does not actually restore the original depth.

Comment: The `red()`, `green()`, and `blue()` functions return a normalized value. Maybe try accessing the `pixels[loc]` value directly instead of passing it through the color functions?

Comment: Good point, but it doesn't seem to work either as inside pixels[] the data is already provided in the 32 bit color format, with 8 Bit for each A, R, G and B. I'm starting to think that it is necessary to code a custom loadImage(...) function.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: The language used here is called "processing" (check processing.org)

Answer (score -1):

You haven't said which library the loadImage command is from.
There might be a 16-bit version, but it's unlikely. 24 bits is a sort of standard, suitable for all but very high end work.

What I suggest you do is take a look at my TIFF loader (which, like loadImage, returns 24 bit images), and modify it to return 16-bit channels. It's not difficult, just  a case of not discarding the lower bits of the larger channel images (float and 16 bit).

Her'e the TIFF loader:
https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/tiffloader